# Trying to find Kina Rd in Toronto

Tags: census-records, canada, 1920s

The 1921 Census of Canada indicates family members lived at 536 Kina Rd, Toronto South District, District #133, Sub-District, Ward 4.  I can't find this street.

Was it renamed or has it disappeared or have development changed it to another name?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the 1921 Canada census image (only 45 names indexed at ancestry.com living in Toronto* with keyword Kina), the street name is "King W" not "Kina Rd".

This is borne out by "Spadina Ave" on the next census image. (Spadina is a major cross-street of **King Street West** in Toronto.